# Is it possible to use Spring Boot/Security + Oauth2/OpenId Connect with custom server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

All the tutorials I find are using google/facebook/github to log in. So tells me that put this in the properties file:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration: 
          google: 
            client-id: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            client-secret: "EATESFGEASFSFEFSFFSFSFSFSFSF"
```

But what if I want to use anything else that is not google/facebook/github/any other popular site.

How to implement Oauth2+OpenId Connect if I have a custom server that should be used?

Comment: it is well documented in the official spring security documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-override-boot-autoconfig always start there and not by trying to find tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Keycloak by example

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc-provider:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8881/auth/realms/springboot
        registration:
          oidc-provider:
            client-id: springboot-okay
            client-secret: daba1d31-80a0-4bab-8063-d721195a3579
```

Where issuer-uri is the uri that your Authorization Server use.
See this image:

[Screenshot - Configuration used by Keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Zgx.png)